# Why do I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this prime number check?

Tags: java, arrays

I was finding out highest prime factor which divides num, as shown in program,
there's a issue with array and

```
arr[j] = i;
j++;
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at primenum.main(primenum.java:13)
```

```
//to find highest prime factor
public class primenum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          double num = 600851475143.0;
           int j = 1;
          int arr[] = {j};

          for(int i=2; i<=num/2; i++)
          {
              if((num%i) == 0 )
              {
                  arr[j] = i;
                  j++;
              }

          }
          // take the last item from array, coz its last big prime
          System.out.println("largest prime is "+ arr[j-1]);

    }
}
```

What is best way to solve this problem??

I'm solving this problem by,

- checking factors until num/2,
- push all into an array,
- check last element......

For prime I need to do more, but I'm stuck in initial stage.

Comment: I love it when people ask easyish questions, you get six different ways to say the exact same thing--fun to watch.  +1 :)  Have fun picking the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are finding all divisors of `num`; one of these will be the largest prime factor. Two related facts alone should help make the problem tractable for smallish numbers:
1. If `d` is a divisor, then so is `num/d`.
2. you needn't check for any divisors greater than the `sqrt(num)`.

To keep track of divisors, use a Set object.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
int arr[] = {j};
```

Creates an array that only contains the value of `j` when it is executed. You probably want

```
int arr[] = new int[j];
```

UPDATE: Based on the answer you left below, trial division is taking too long. The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a classic algorithm that is pretty efficient, but the [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) is one of the most advanced algorithms for finding primes.

Answer (score 2):

By creating array arr[] = {j}, you have created an array which contains simply j, or 1. That means the length of the array is 1, because it contains 1 element. Thus, arr[1] is out of bounds. Java does not dynamically resize arrays, so you must create a sufficiently large array to contain all of the data you plan to hold. Either that or use something like an ArrayList, which is dynamically resizeable.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java are not lists: once allocated, your array won't grow magically.

You created the array with:

`int arr[] = {j};`

thus the array has one cell only.

You should initialise your array with at least `num/2` cells,
with something like
`int arr[] = new int[num/2]; arr[0] = j;`

Comment: since my variable num is double, i can't do int[num/2] ?

Comment: @tonio num is a huge number.  An int array of num/2 would be ~1.2 terabytes.

Comment: In this case, you should not use an array. And your program do not use the values in this array, except for the last one. Why not simply use an int value ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you start j = 1 and your array only has one element in it to begin, so on the first pass through your for loop you look for arr[1], but the first element in an array is at arr[0]. Java arrays are zero indexed meaning if you have 10 elements in the array they are located in arr[0] to arr[9].